# Save illegal string in a hidden input

Tags: javascript, c#, razor

I have an encoded string and I want to set it in a hidden field using javascript but I get 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL'

I can't replace these illegal characters with anything because I use them for decoding

string example

```
"wcdkH~`pnVAvIAzB?pAmA?Q?aBCiEi@yCEc@Iy@Ue@Iw@AkBCg@?GGi@G]Ga@SQOQSg@cAMM]W_@Qc@Ic@AcADIHaDCeCCkAAg@I[Qw@m@iAiAkBcBg@tAiAdDoKgLq@m@sC{B[E?f@AzIElEIxC[jJcAtRc@lEWhA[|@c@l@i@`@[NWDi@Bo@G_AOw@As@?WB]HKFm@h@Y\\U`@g@|AO~@E~@@~@F~@XvAPh@Vf@f@t@l@p@|@~@x@`Ab@t@\\x@T|@PbAZlCLn@RpBl@fGd@fEI|AId@Q^QZqCZyBLoB]iDwAgAq@u@]iCqAoB[c@AwHmAgAG{@BmA^e@Ta@^WVg@p@]n@qFvLsGvNSl@YdAUnAO|Ac@`IyEvz@eAvQ"
```

I am passing this value from c# into a razor view. if there is anyway to set it in the hidden field using javascript without losing any info that will be good.

Comment: You'll need to escape the single quote(s).

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript strings are surrounded by quotes. you can have quotes in the middle of a string, but you have to escape them with a "\". You might need to escape special characters. if your string has combinations of single quotes and double quotes then escaping those characters should help you.

sample escaping double quotes:

```
var token = "asdasd\"asdasd";
```

looks like your sample string does not throw error. see code in link:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYKpEP